# How to delete all rows by group except the first and the last one in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-delete

I have data like this

```
Id Name AuthorId 
----------------
1  AAA  2
2  BBB  2
3  CCC  2
4  DDD  3
5  EEE  3
```

I need a query which will delete all rows by group AuthorId if there are more then 2, except the first and the last one.

For example, in the above data, the second row should be deleted, because, for `AuthorId = 2`, I have 3 rows, but for `AuthorId = 3`, nothing will be deleted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Row_number()` twice and delete non-terminals

```
delete t
from (
   select *,
      row_number() over(partition by [AuthorId]  order by [Id]) n1,
      row_number() over(partition by [AuthorId]  order by [Id] desc) n2
   from tablename
) t
where n1 > 1 and n2 > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a union for min and max id and NOT in the result for this subquery

```
delete from my_table 
where id  NOT  IN  (


    select  min(id) 
    from my_table 
    group by AuthorId 
    union 
    select max(id)
    from my_table 
    group by AuthorId 

)
```

Comment: what about the condition that the delete operation should occur only if the group has items >= 2, and what if my Id is GUID?

Comment: If you wnat save the first and last record  you can't use having count > 2  ..  because  you don't know which records delete  ... for GUID or ID if are primary key  .. is the same  ..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Declare @t table (id int,name varchar(50),Authorid int)

insert into @t values (1,'AAA',2)
insert into @t values (2,'BBB',2)
insert into @t values (3,'CCC',2)
insert into @t values (4,'FFF',2)
insert into @t values (5,'DDD',3)
insert into @t values (6,'EEE',3)
;with cte as
(
select * from (
select *,count(*) over (partition by authorid) cnt from @t
) t
where cnt > 2
)

delete a from cte b join @t a on a.id=b.id where b.id not in (select min(id) from cte group by Authorid) and b.id not in (select max(id) from cte group by Authorid)

select * from @t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Declare @Temp_Data table (id int,name varchar(50),Authorid int)

insert into @Temp_Data values (1,'AAA',2)
insert into @Temp_Data values (2,'BBB',2)
insert into @Temp_Data values (3,'CCC',2)
insert into @Temp_Data values (4,'DDD',3)
insert into @Temp_Data values (5,'EEE',3)

Delete a
from @Temp_Data as a
inner join @Temp_Data as b on a.authorid=b.authorid and b.id > a.id
inner join @Temp_Data as c on a.authorid=c.authorid and c.id < a.id

select * from @Temp_Data
```

Answer (score 0):

With `EXISTS`:

```
delete t
from tablename t
where 
  exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where authorid = t.authorid and id > t.id
  )
  and
  exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where authorid = t.authorid and id < t.id
  )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88de473905686efe615130d9487e8e7f).
Results:

```
Id  Name    AuthorId
1   AAA     2
3   CCC     2
4   DDD     3
5   EEE     3
```